# Using System.Windows.Forms

Tags: c#, windows, forms, mouse, system

I Am trying to control the cursor in Visual Studio 2010 C#.  I have the code for it (`Cursor.Position = new Point(x, y);`) but I need to include `System.Windows.Forms` to use that, or it just gives me an error.  The thing is, it can't find Forms under windows!  I have included `System.Windows.Forms.dll` in my assembly, but still no luck.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the Target framework of your project to .NET 4 Framework Client profile.

/Tibi

Answer (score 0):

In VS2010 go to project -> add reference -> .net tab -> look for system.windows.forms -> ok, then add the using directive

Comment: I did that! "I have included System.Windows.Forms.dll in my assembly"